# Swift grab "My Card" CNContact

Tags: macos, swift, swift2, cncontact

I can't seem to figure out how to grab a users "My Card" from contacts. I am developing a native Mac application using swift.

Comment: you are looking for CNContactStore @selector(unifiedMeContactWithKeysToFetch:error:)

Answer (score 0):

It's not from (the brand new as of MacOS 10.11) CNContact, but MacOS's [ABAddressBook framework has a method called `me()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ABAddressBook/me) which will return the logged in user's ABPerson record.

And to get the vCard equivalent, [call `vCardRepresentation()` on that ABPerson object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABPerson_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ABPerson/vCardRepresentation).

The nice thing about the above solution is that it will work on older MacOS versions (e.g. MacOS 10.9, 10.10).

Marek points out the `unifiedMeContactWithKeysToFetch:` API in CNContactStore, but at the time of me typing this answer, it's only documented in the .h header file in the SDK and not in [the CNContactStore documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContactStore_Class/).

Comment: CNContactStore is the place where to get CNContact from. There is "me" contact as well. Basically if you don't save contact there your app will crash but that's a different topic

Comment: Thanks for noticing that @marekh ; I only see five hits on that API in Google today.

Comment: If it's in the header file, you can use it. Sometimes the documentation lags behind the header files. (Try to find the function reference documentation for Core Audio. Go on. I dare you.)

Comment: It is now also in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CNContact api for this, but it is only available in macOS 10.11+, and not in iOS of any version to date.

(For iOS, reverting to ABAddressBook does not solve the problem, as the `me()` method there is likewise only for MacOS, though back as far as macOS 10.2+.)

```
import Contacts

let nameKeys = [
    CNContactNamePrefixKey,
    CNContactGivenNameKey,
    CNContactMiddleNameKey,
    CNContactFamilyNameKey,
    CNContactNameSuffixKey,
    ] as [CNKeyDescriptor]

do {
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    let me = try contactStore.unifiedMeContactWithKeys(toFetch: nameKeys)
} catch let error {
    print("Failed to retreive Me contact: \(error)")
}
```

Could of course also fetch additional keys:

```
let allContactKeys = [
    CNContactNamePrefixKey,
    CNContactGivenNameKey,
    CNContactMiddleNameKey,
    CNContactFamilyNameKey,
    CNContactNameSuffixKey,
    CNContactOrganizationNameKey,
    CNContactDepartmentNameKey,
    CNContactJobTitleKey,
    CNContactBirthdayKey,
    CNContactNicknameKey,
    CNContactNoteKey,
    CNContactNonGregorianBirthdayKey,
    CNContactPreviousFamilyNameKey,
    CNContactPhoneticGivenNameKey,
    CNContactPhoneticMiddleNameKey,
    CNContactPhoneticFamilyNameKey,
    CNContactImageDataKey,
    CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey,
    CNContactImageDataAvailableKey,
    CNContactTypeKey,
    CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
    CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
    CNContactPostalAddressesKey,
    CNContactDatesKey,
    CNContactUrlAddressesKey,
    CNContactRelationsKey,
    CNContactSocialProfilesKey,
    CNContactInstantMessageAddressesKey,
    ] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
```

Comment: it is posible for mobile app?

Comment: Nope. Not supported on iOS unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking, this is now possible via `CNContactStore` using this [unifiedMeContactWithKeys(toFetch:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore/unifiedmecontactwithkeys(tofetch:)) method. Supported in all apple platforms.