# Get me card details from Contacts

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode8, ios10

Is there any way to fetch the My Card details from Contacts or from Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendar > My Info.

I have tried `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"];` but this returns null.

Comment: what "Card" details ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal Owner information

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably no longer needed, but it looks like you can do this in macOS with `CNContactStore().unifiedMeContactWithKeys(toFetch: keysToFetch)`

See this related question for more information:
[Swift grab "My Card" CNContact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291257/swift-grab-my-card-cncontact)